# coredump file get line number to a shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, coredump

I'm using gdb to analyze a core dump file. The executable is linked to a shared library, both the executable and shared library is compiled with `-g` flag, in the `bt` I can see the line num in executable, but not the shared library. Any idea to solve this?

I open the core file in this way:

```
gdb /path/to/executable /path/to/core/file
```

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f4e7711b438 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007f4e7711d03a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007f4e7858b8b1 in std::pair<tsmap3::NearestPtResult, double> tsmap3::IndexTree::GetNearestPt2<tsmap3::LaneImpl>(tsmap3::Point3d const&, tsmap3::Point3d const&, double, std::function<tsmap3::NearestPtResult (tsmap3::Point3d const&, tsmap3::LaneImpl const*)>, std::function<bool (tsmap3::LaneImpl const*)>, std::unordered_set<unsigned long, std::hash<unsigned long>, std::equal_to<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> >&) const () from /home/ziqi.liu/code/map-lane-map3/build/src/tsmap3.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#3  0x00007f4e784d93a0 in tsmap3::NearestPtResult tsmap3::GridSystem::GetNearestPt<tsmap3::LaneImpl>(tsmap3::Point3d const&, double, std::function<tsmap3::NearestPtResult (tsmap3::Point3d const&, tsmap3::LaneImpl const*)> const&, std::function<bool (tsmap3::LaneImpl const*)> const&) () from /home/ziqi.liu/code/map-lane-map3/build/src/tsmap3.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#4  0x00007f4e784bf201 in tsmap3::TSMapImpl::GetNearestRefPt(tsmap3::Point3d const&, double, std::vector<tsmap3::Lane::Property, std::allocator<tsmap3::Lane::Property> > const&, bool) const ()
   from /home/ziqi.liu/code/map-lane-map3/build/src/tsmap3.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#5  0x00007f4e78537fb3 in tsmap3::TSMap::GetNearestRefPt(tsmap3::Point3d const&, double, std::vector<tsmap3::Lane::Property, std::allocator<tsmap3::Lane::Property> > const&, bool) const ()
   from /home/ziqi.liu/code/map-lane-map3/build/src/tsmap3.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#6  0x00000000004230d2 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at /home/ziqi.liu/code/map-lane-map3/examples/bench_get_nearest_ref_pt.cpp:54
```

the `/home/ziqi.liu/code/map-lane-map3/build/src/tsmap3.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` is the so file for shared library.

I do have the source files for that shared library, I guess I need to hint the gdb where to find the source files somehow

Comment: sharedlibrary?  https://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/sharedlibrary

Comment: @AllanWind it seems that gdb already loaded symbol for that shared library when I input `sharedlibrary tsmap3`, but it didn't show the line number. So I guess gdb was not able to find source files, is there anyway to let gdb know the source file location?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I realized that the shared library has no symbol table for debugging, there must be something wrong in its compile.....